# My entire screen is frozen when installing ubuntu 14.04 (latest version) for windows 7

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I've seen other questions and responses about how to skip that step, but my problem is that I can not select anything on the screen (cursor moves though). Any help? Is there a control alt delete on ubuntu? How do I get out of this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is a CTRL+ALT+DEL but when I used it on the same problem, it loads Ubuntu, but does not connect to the internet anymore.